# My chrome lost its passwords and stopped logging me into my favourite sites when it has them

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, cookies, auto-login

Chrome used to remember that I am logged in to my web Outlook, my Facebook etc and open them logged in. A library visit gone wrong seems to have removed my passwords but even now that I have added some back, I still encounter this. And I checked that I am accepting cookies too...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would do to hopefully resolve this issue..

1.I would update to the latest version of Google Chrome, in previous versions this used to be a bug

2.I would ensure that Google Chrome is set to keep local data, this can be achieved by following these steps:
      a)Go to settings, then advanced settings
      b)privacy and security, then choose content settings, then click on cookies
      c)Inside the cookies menu, ensure that "Keep Local data only until you quit your 
      browser is unchecked

3.Ensure the save password box is enabled, click settings, then autofill, then passwords, make sure the box "Offer to save passwords" is checked.

If making any of these changes, make sure to restart the browser so that they take effect.